# Vue Js & Rails: How to display image attached with blob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vuejs2, blob, rails-activestorage

> I'm uploading image files using Rails `Active Storage` gem and they are being hosted in AWS S3. However, I wonder how could I display the image attached to each record in my Vue Js component. I have  tried to directly call the image `file name` but it did not work; Also, I tried to use the AWS `image_url` but after some time I realized that it was an incorrect approach. What would be your suggestions to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I am presenting the same problem

Comment: Yes, I use the normal image tag for HTML but my source was AWSPATH+blob_image_key! So it would be something like `https://bucket-name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/blob-image-url`